# Removing items for a list using a loop in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to programming in general and have started with Python. I am working through various problems to try and better my understanding.

I am trying to define a function that removes vowels from a string. This is what I have tried:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        new.append(text[i])
    print new
    for x in new:
        if x == "e" or x == "E" or x == "a" or x == "A" or x == "i" or x == "I" or x == "o" or x == "O" or x == "u" or x == "U":
            new.remove(x)
    return "".join(new)
```

This is removing vowels from the first words of a string, but not the final word:

eg:

```
anti_vowel("Hey look words!")    
returns: "Hy lk words!"
```

Can somebody please explain where I am going wrong so I can learn from this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you just *not `append` it* if you don't want it, rather than adding them all then removing some?

Answer (score 5):

You [should not delete items from a list while iterating through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python). You will find numerous posts on Stack Overflow explaining why.

I would use the `filter` function

```
>>> vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
>>> myString = 'This is my string that has vowels in it'
>>> filter(lambda i : i not in vowels, myString)
'Ths s my strng tht hs vwls n t'
```

Written as a function, this would be

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    return filter(lambda letter : letter not in vowels, text)
```

Test

```
>>> anti_vowel(myString)
'Ths s my strng tht hs vwls n t'
```

Comment: Ah I see. I will spend some time reviewing list iteration do's and don't's. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have approached this a bit backwards. Firstly, note that:

```
new = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    new.append(text[i])
```

is just:

```
new = list(text)
```

Secondly, why not check before `append`ing, rather than afterwards? Then you only have to iterate over the characters once. This could be:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    """Remove all vowels from the supplied text.""" # explanatory docstring
    non_vowels = [] # clear variable names
    vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU") # sets allow fast membership tests
    for char in text: # iterate directly over characters, no need for 'i'
        if char not in vowels: # test membership of vowels
            non_vowels.append(char) # add non-vowels only
    return "".join(non_vowels)
```

A quick example:

```
>>> anti_vowel("Hey look words!")
'Hy lk wrds!'
```

This simplifies further to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    """Remove all vowels from the supplied text."""
    vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
    return "".join([char for char in text if char not in vowels])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comp:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    return "".join([x for x in text if x not in vowels])
print anti_vowel("Hey look words!")
Hy lk wrds!
```

The list comprehension filters the vowels from the words.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it succinctly with a comprehension:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch.upper() not in 'AEIOU')
```

Comment: Better to pass a list comprehension than just the generator expression; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3001761

Comment: Ah that's really helpful, thank you. I didn't know you could use "join" like that.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is an indexed operation. When you remove an item from a list while iterating over it, you essentially change the indices of every item in the list that follows the item you removed. When you loop over the list

```
['h','e','y',' ','l','o','o','k',' ','w','o','r','d','s']
```

whilst removing an item in `'aeiou'`, on the second iteration of the loop, you remove `'e'` from your list and your left with

```
['h','y',' ','l','o','o','k',' ','w','o','r','d','s']
```

then on the third iteration, instead of testing your if statement on the `y`, which was originally in the third position, it is now testing it on the `' '`, which is what is in the third position of the the modified list.

```
mylist.remove(x)
```

will search for the first matching value of `x` in`mylist` and remove it. When your loop gets to the first `'o'` in the list, it removes it, thereby changing the index of the following `'o'` by `-1`. On the next iteration of the loop, it is looking at `'k'` instead of the subsequent `'o'`.

However, why then did your function remove the first two `'o'`s and not the last one?

Your loop looked at the first `'o'`, not the second `'o'`, and looked at the third `'o'`. In total your loop found two matches for `'o'` and performed the `remove` function on both. And again, since the `remove` function will find the first matching item in the list and remove it, that's why it removed the first two `'o'`s, although for the removal of the second `'o'` your loop was actually iterating over the third `'o'`.

You were fortunate to have done this test on a string with consecutive vowels. Had you done it on a string without consecutive vowels, you would have removed all the vowels with your function and it would have appeared to work as you intended.